# Query about slowing computer

Tags: laptop, ssd, storage, dell-latitude

My Dell latitude 3540 (i5-4210U @1.7Ghz  2.40Ghz) (8Gb Ram 64 bit os on x64 processor) running (Windows 8.1 Pro)  is getting a really slow and a technician recently recommended me to change out the existing HDD for a SSD to improve the laptop. Not sure if this is wise or even recommended.or if I should just wait and get a new laptop in the near future.

Comment: An SSD is a faster storage volume so yes the computer will seem faster. But really, you should look into why its running slower.        On a side note: this -1 business should be outlawed, or only allowed in the must egregious cases.  This new contributor is doing the best they can to ask an honest question and who ever -1'd them should be ashamed.

Comment: Thank you so much , that is definitely something i will try to look into and thanks for supporting me on -1 issue.

Comment: There are many reasons why your computer could be slowing down. Your computer is old. A new SSD would likely improve things, but there's no guarantee. It's difficult to say with certainty that THIS specific act will improve. However, the SSD is one of the easier things you can do to likely improve your computer's responsiveness. The technician was not wrong to recommend it.